# switch block not executing correctly on arduino C++

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I have a function that performs a `switch` on a single variable against some constants.
However, it's not executing correctly.

Using this code, the `actionType` is `4` (`LED_ACTION`) so falls into the "LED action" block.

```
const int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN;

// Actions
const int NULL_ACTION = 0;
const int SERVO_ACTION = 1;
const int SERVOOP_ACTION = 2;
const int BUZZER_ACTION = 3;
const int LED_ACTION = 4;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  int actionType = 4;

  Serial.print("Action type: ");
  Serial.println(actionType);

  switch (actionType) {
    case BUZZER_ACTION:
      Serial.println("Buzzer action");
//      int buzzerPitch = 123;
      // int buzzerDuration = 1000;
      // tone(buzzerPin, buzzerPitch, buzzerDuration);
      break;

    case LED_ACTION:
      Serial.println("LED action");
      int ledState = HIGH;
      digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
      break;

    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown action");
      // Do Nothing
      break;
  }

  int actionSleep = 1000;
  Serial.print("Action sleeping for: ");
  Serial.println(actionSleep);
  delay(actionSleep);
}

void loop() {
  
}
```

This can be seen in the log output (and the LED flashing):

```
Action type: 4
LED action
Action sleeping for: 1000
```

The problem comes when I add anything else to the other statements.
Uncommenting a single assignment in the `BUZZER_ACTION` block causes it to... It seems to just skip the entire thing, not logging any of them, or the default action, or flashing the LED.

```
Action type: 4
Action sleeping for: 1000
```

Am I doing anything stupid here? What's going on?

This is running on an Arduino Uno r3, with the sketch uploaded from the Arduino IDE, and VSCode.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Arduino C++ does not like declarations inside the `switch` block, even if they're not conflicting.

Moving them outside works without issue.

```
const int ledPin = LED_BUILTIN;

// Actions
const int NULL_ACTION = 0;
const int SERVO_ACTION = 1;
const int SERVOOP_ACTION = 2;
const int BUZZER_ACTION = 3;
const int LED_ACTION = 4;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  int actionType = 4;

  Serial.print("Action type: ");
  Serial.println(actionType);

  int buzzerPitch;
  int buzzerDuration;
  int ledState;
  switch (actionType) {
    case BUZZER_ACTION:
      Serial.println("Buzzer action");
      buzzerPitch = 123;
      buzzerDuration = 1000;
      tone(buzzerPin, buzzerPitch, buzzerDuration);
      break;

    case LED_ACTION:
      Serial.println("LED action");
      ledState = HIGH;
      digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
      break;

    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown action");
      // Do Nothing
      break;
  }

  int actionSleep = 1000;
  Serial.print("Action sleeping for: ");
  Serial.println(actionSleep);
  delay(actionSleep);
}

void loop() {
  
}
```

Comment: Or you can put the code of each case inside brackets